# The same calculation in CUDA output differently in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I built a simple network using pytorch in GPU GTX 1080ti and initiate the network weight at the beginning and randomly initiate input tensors. And then I calculate the network output 10 times but each output has a little difference(in this phase, all weights and input are FIXED, I have printed them out for a check.). as shown following:

[image]

I wonder why will it happen? Is it because of the Floating point precision of the GPU? Thanks for any suggestion:)

---

**SUMMARY**

Finally, I figure out what happened, the code looks like:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.functional as F
# import torch.utils.data.dataloader as dataloader

class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    params = [
      [3,16],
      [16,32],
      [32,32],
    ]
    self.model_list = nn.ModuleList()
    for each in params:
      self.model_list.append(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=each[0],
                  out_channels=each[1],
                  kernel_size=(3,3),
                  stride=(1,1))
      )
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(stride=3, kernel_size=(3,3))
    # self.fcn = nn.Linear(in_features=3200, out_features=10).cuda()
  def forward(self, inputv):
    tmp = inputv
    for each in self.model_list:
      tmp = each(tmp)
    for each in range(2):
      tmp = self.pool(tmp)
    tmp = tmp.view(tmp.shape[0], -1)
    fcn = nn.Linear(in_features=tmp.shape[1], out_features=10).cuda()
    # build a new layer here will initiate the weight every time i call forward, which make everything mess.
    tmp = fcn(tmp)
    print(tmp.shape)
    return tmp.mean()

model = Net().cuda()
inputv = np.ones(shape=(32,3,100,100))
inputv = inputv.astype(np.float32)
inputv = torch.tensor(inputv).cuda()

model.eval()
for each in range(10):
  n = model(inputv)
  print(n)
```

The problem is that I build a new layer `fcn` in `forward` which will initiate the weight every time I call it. Once I build the layer in the **init**, every problem gone. However it's reasonable why I build some layer in forward. Sometimes some parameter needed to calculate dynamic instead of specifying manually such as the `fcn` input_dimension. Just like what I do in TensorFlow, it will manage a pipeline and I don't need to worry about some parameters after I change the network structure. What should I do if I want to build a network in tensorflow style? Thanks for any suggestion:)

Comment: Can you share the minimal code to reproduce>

Comment: @UmangGupta I finally figure out what happened and i have edited my question. But i another problem comes to me which is related, please have a look.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong here,... but it is funny I can't see any edit

Comment: @UmangGupta I just finished that, sorry for my comment post in advance. XD

Comment: I don't understand why you need a new fcn layer "EVERYTIME" you do forward? I have never seen such a use case. Also, if you want the weights to be fixed, you can compute weights in init and apply them everytime in forward.

Comment: Ok, I read your post again and see that you specifically want to decide `fcn` parameters based on input dimension. In case of the torch, you actually have to specify input parameters, it doesn't infer like tensorflow. But still, you will declare only once and not every time you make a forward pass.

Comment: i add a flag to avoid the repeatedly initiate in forward, thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, in that case i add a flag like `self._is_forward` to make sure not to repeatedly build.